# Is it okay use lower Kotlin version than coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I've found that companion version for Kotlin 1.5.20 is Coroutine 1.5.1 version [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#kotlinxcoroutines).

But is it okay if I use Coroutine 1.5.1 with Kotlin 1.4.3?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your project is just going to inherit higher kotlin version from coroutine module no?

Comment: @Pawel you can specify strict version of kotlin to prevent inheriting

Comment: your original link wasn't relevant so i removed it, glad to see you posted the correct link now